# Invert Y axis on coordinate plane?

Tags: equation

On a coordinate plane, what is the equation to flip the image upside down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be as simple as `y = -y`?

Comment: Yes, probably. I will implement the equation in my code and get back to you.

Comment: There's a deeper problem in my code. I'll mark this as answered.